# Too much space after Slider

Tags: dynamic

In part of a dynamic module I have a slider and I wish to put the units after the value. So I have done this:

```
 style = FontSize -> 24;
f1 = 0; f2 = 10;
Row[{
  Style["Frequency ", style],
  Style[Slider[Dynamic[f], {f1, f2}, 
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "DownArrow"}, 
    ImageSize -> {6 72, 0.5 72}], style],
  Style["Hz", style]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you may see the units are way over to the right well away from the number. I want the units just after the number with no significant gap. How do I do this?

Playing around I put a frame around the slider using

```
style = FontSize -> 24;
f1 = 0; f2 = 10;
Row[{
  Style["Frequency ", style],
  Framed[Style[
    Slider[Dynamic[f], {f1, f2}, 
     Appearance -> {"Labeled", "DownArrow"}, 
     ImageSize -> {5 72, 0.5 72}], style]],
  Style["Hz", style]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is now clear. For some reason Mathematica puts lots of space around the slider particularly on the right. How do I get rid of this extra space?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**  Use the option [`DefaultOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultOptions.html) in `Slider` to change the `ImageSize` of `InputField`:

```
defaultoptions = {InputField -> {BaseStyle -> style, ImageSize -> {{30, 100}, 36}}};

Row[{Style["Frequency", style], 
     Framed[Slider[Dynamic[f], {f1, f2}, 
       Appearance -> {"Labeled", "DownArrow"}, 
       ImageSize -> {5 72, 0.5 72}, 
       DefaultOptions -> defaultoptions]], 
    Style["Hz", style]}, Spacer[1]]
```

[image]

or

```
Row[Style[#, style] & /@ 
  {"frequency", 
   Framed @ Slider[Dynamic[f], {f1, f2}, 
     Appearance -> {"Labeled", "DownArrow"}, 
     ImageSize -> {5 72, 0.5 72}, 
     DefaultOptions -> defaultoptions], 
   "Hz"}, 
  Spacer[1]]
```

> same picture

**Original answer:**

You can use [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) or [`Panel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Panel.html) using the second and third arguments to specify the labels and their positions:

```
Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[f], {f1, f2}], 
  {"frequency", Row[{Dynamic[f], "Hz"}, Spacer[2]]}, 
  {Left, Right}, 
  LabelStyle -> style]
```

[image]

```
Panel[Slider[Dynamic[f], {f1, f2}], 
 {"frequency", Row[{Dynamic[f], "Hz"}, Spacer[2]]}, 
 {Left, Right}, 
 LabelStyle -> style]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However the `Appearance -> "Labeled"` option makes the number an input field. So one can type in a number and the slide jumps to this value. I guess to give me the functionality  we need to make your second `Dynamic` an `InputField` and connect it to the slider. All possible, and adds to the dynamic overhead,  but complicated when all we are doing is working on layout.

Comment: @Hugh, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks. Lot's of new option usages I was unfamiliar with.  The not so obvious  `InputField`  is now given options with an interesting use of `ImageSize`. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

The `Appearance -> "Labeled"` seems to be inserting the space. Perhaps make the label yourself instead:

```
style = FontSize -> 24;
f1 = 0; f2 = 10;

Row[{Style["Frequency ", style],
  Style[Slider[Dynamic[f], {f1, f2}], style],
  Style[Dynamic[" " ~~ ToString[f] ~~ " Hz"], style]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However the `Appearance -> "Labeled"` option makes the number an input field. So one can type in a number and the slide jumps to this value. I guess to give me the functionality  we need to make your second `Dynamic` an `InputField` and connect it to the slider. All possible, and adds to the dynamic overhead,  but complicated when all we are doing is working on layout.